# Medoo - Incluir consulta MySQL directamente

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un archivo con un modelo de consulta que no logro comprender y necesito poder cambiarla, pero cambiando el modelo deja de funcionar así que debería ser de esa misma como esta, pero modificando la consulta o por lo menos quefuncione así, este es el archivo actual y la consulta da el resultado:

```
<?php
require_once('medoo.php');
require_once('../../php/inc.php');
$database = new medoo([
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => $DB,
    'server' => $SERVIDOR,
    'username' => $USUARIO,
    'password' => $CLAVE,
    'charset' => 'utf8'
]);
$tbl = $_GET['tabla'];
$accion = $_GET['accion'];
$tabla = $TABLA[$tbl];
$columnas['usuarios'] = ['id', 'Nombre', 'Cedula', 'Empresa', 'FechaReg', 'activo'];
var_dump($TABLA['usuarios']);
$data['usuarios'] = $database->select($TABLA['usuarios'], $columnas['usuarios']);
if ($accion == 'leer') {
    $salida = [];
    if ($tbl = 'usuarios') {
        foreach($data[$tbl] as $llave => $dato) {
            if($dato['activo']) {
                array_pop($dato);
                array_push($salida, $dato);
            }
        }
        print_r(json_encode($salida, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    } 
}
function obtenerID($id, $tabla, $campo){
    foreach($tabla as $dato) {
        if ($dato['id'] == $id) {
            return $dato[$campo];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Pero debo modificar esa consulta y hacerla de esta forma

`SELECT * FROM usuarios u LEFT JOIN cursos r ON r.CodUsuario=u.id LEFT JOIN listadocursos c ON r.CodCurso=c.id ORDER BY u.id ASC`

En el archivo medoo.php esta la función

```
public function select($table, $join, $columns = null, $where = null)
{
    $query = $this->query($this->select_context($table, $join, $columns, $where));
    return $query ? $query->fetchAll(
        (is_string($columns) && $columns != '*') ? PDO::FETCH_COLUMN : PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Creo que lo que te será más cómodo, es utilizar directamente el método
>   [query](https://medoo.in/api/query) de medoo

Lo que pones en el enunciado en primer lugar, es un trozo de código en [PHP] (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Lo segundo sí que es una consulta [SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) Son lenguages completamente diferentes.

En este caso, lo que tienes en el código en PHP, es una consulta a base de datos mediante [medoo](https://www.webbizarro.com/aplicaciones/1385/medoo-un-framework-php-para-base-de-datos/), que viene a ser un adaptador de base de datos para PHP. [Aquí está la documentación de cómo hacer consultas con Medoo](https://medoo.in/api/select)

Y llegados, aquí, creo que lo lógico será:

```
<?php
require_once('medoo.php');
require_once('../../php/inc.php');
$database = new medoo([
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => $DB,
    'server' => $SERVIDOR,
    'username' => $USUARIO,
    'password' => $CLAVE,
    'charset' => 'utf8'
]);
$tbl = $_GET['tabla'];
$accion = $_GET['accion'];
$tabla = $TABLA[$tbl];
$columnas['usuarios'] = ['id', 'Nombre', 'Cedula', 'Empresa', 'FechaReg', 'activo'];
var_dump($TABLA['usuarios']);

// Aquí es donde realizas la consulta con el método query en vez de construyéndola de manera compleja

$data['usuarios'] = $database->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios u LEFT JOIN cursos r ON r.CodUsuario=u.id LEFT JOIN listadocursos c ON r.CodCurso=c.id ORDER BY u.id ASC")->fetchAll();


if ($accion == 'leer') {
    $salida = [];
    if ($tbl = 'usuarios') {
        foreach($data[$tbl] as $llave => $dato) {
            if($dato['activo']) {
                array_pop($dato);
                array_push($salida, $dato);
            }
        }
        print_r(json_encode($salida, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    } 
}
function obtenerID($id, $tabla, $campo){
    foreach($tabla as $dato) {
        if ($dato['id'] == $id) {
            return $dato[$campo];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda